# Explain this websocket ticker data please

Tags: api, trading, bots, live-data, websockets

I've looked at various websocket feeds from crpyto exchanges and they in general are like this

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "ticker",
  "params": {
    "ask": "0.054464",
    "bid": "0.054463",
    "last": "0.054463",
    "open": "0.057133",
    "low": "0.053615",
    "high": "0.057559",
    "volume": "33068.346",
    "volumeQuote": "1832.687530809",
    "timestamp": "2017-10-19T15:45:44.941Z",
    "symbol": "ETHBTC"
  }
}
```

As i understand a ticket is a feed on every price change.. so sure enough the wss feed streams updates for the coin pair as the price changes.

What is not clear is what do the `open`, `high`, `low`, `last` fields represent ? The open of what ? Since the previous price change just milliseconds ago ?

Can someone explain wither from a polled REST feed or streamed websocket feed what these numbers are really referring to please given the gap bet between received data is so short ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**open** is the price at which a security first trades upon the opening of an exchange on a given trading day; for example, the New York Stock Exchange opens at precisely 9:30 a.m. Eastern.

**High** the highest value within 24 hours.

**Low** the lowest value of 24 hours.

**Last** as the price gets update upon live trades so, last is the last trade price. for example, if I've sold my bitcoins for 11,000 so last will be 11,000